# Regex - How to capture Markdown H2 title and content in two named capture group

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, regex-group

Hi i have a markdow text like the one below and i want to slice it in H2 tilte, H2 content

```
## **Intro**


* bla bla
* bla bla bla


## Tortilla

* chico
* chica

### 1. sub-section

* and another bla.
```

Regex result should be :

title 1:

```
Intro
```

content 1:

```
* bla bla
* bla bla bla
```

title 2:

```
Tortilla
```

content 2:

```
* chico
* chica

### 1. sub-section

* and another bla.
```

I tried with this regex

`/^## (?<title>.*)(?<content>.*(?:\n(?!##).*)*)/gm`

But doesn't catch the sub-section content.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

The regex below produces the output desired from the input you have given.

```
^##\s(?<title>.*)\n(?<content>(?:(?!##\s).*\n?)+)
```

Explanation of most pieces:

| piece | description |
| --- | --- |
| `^##\s` | match lines that begin with H2 |
| `(?<title>.*)\n` | capture everything after the H2 and discard the new line |
| `(?:(?!##\s).*\n?)+` | match all text that doesn't start a line with H2, including any new lines |

The primary issue with your attempt is that you are trying to account for the new line after `title` by including it in `content` when it just needs to be discarded.

The secondary issue is that you're not providing a differentiator for lines that start with `##` that are not H2 (i.e. there must be whitespace after the `##`)

Note: the optional new line (`\n?`) at the end of `content` is required when the input does not end with a new line

Comment: elegant and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Since one anyway needs to create a data-structure from all matched group values, one also can choose an approach based on the combination of a simple regex like ... [`/^##\s+(.*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/WQrkqS/1) ... which  will be utilized for [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting the markdown string. The relevant array data then gets [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)d into the final result, an array which features all the `H2` related items, each item consisting of a [sanitized `title` value](https://regex101.com/r/WQrkqS/2) and an as well sanitized `content` value ...

```js
const markdown = `

# Main Topic

maintopic content

maintopic content


## **Intro**


* bla bla
* bla bla bla


## Tortilla

* chico
* chica

### 1. sub-section

* and another bla.`;


const result = markdown

  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/WQrkqS/1]
  .split(/^##\s+(.*)/gm)
  .splice(1)

  .reduce((result, title, idx, arr) => {
    if (idx % 2 === 0) {
      // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/WQrkqS/2]
      const regXTrimNonNumbersLetters = /^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+|[^\p{L}\p{N}]+$/gu;

      result
        .push({
          title: title.replace(regXTrimNonNumbersLetters, '').trim(),
          content: arr[idx + 1].trim(),
        });
    }
    return result;
  }, []);

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit**

And an implementation which used *Tibrogargan's* regex, could look similar to the following one ...

```js
const markdown = `
# Main Topic

maintopic content

maintopic content


## **Intro**


* bla bla
* bla bla bla


## Tortilla

* chico
* chica

### 1. sub-section

* and another bla.`;

const result = [
  ...markdown
    .matchAll(/^##\s(?<title>.*)\n(?<content>(?:(?!##\s).*\n?)+)/gm)
]
.map(({ groups: { title, content } }) => ({

  title: title.replace(/^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+|[^\p{L}\p{N}]+$/gu, '').trim(),
  content: content.trim(),

}));

console.log({ result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```